# Cant downCast from myCoustomClass

Tags: swift, downcast

```
class MyCViewContollerClass:UIViewController{

    var button = UIButton()
}

let storyBoard = UIStoryboard()
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc") as! MyCViewContollerClass
```

Comment: Did you set `MyCViewContollerClass` as the class of the view controller with identifier "vc"?

Comment: Are you using storyboard in Interface Builder?

Comment: No i am using playground ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your storyboard from file:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
```

Or, if you haven't storyboard, you can just create your view controller programmatically:

```
let viewController = MyCViewControllerClass()
```